# unzip file using java

Tags: java

Is there any external jar that can be used to unzip files using java.Some of the codes to unzip a file using java available in the internet showing inconsistent behavior for zip files of type .zip /.rar.Is there any good java code to unzip a zip file.

Comment: It's more helpful for us and yourself if you elaborate "showing inconsistent behavior" in more detail instead of posting such a non-constructive question which basically asks for code/tool/API. We can't suggest anything as long as we don't know what code/tool/API you've used. You might for instance already have tried/used it! Note that RAR files are not the same as ZIP files and thus require a different treatment.

Comment: files that end in `.rar` are **NOT** zip files ...

Comment: rar files are not the same as zip files. You likely can find a library on the internet to decompress a rar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAR format is proprietary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR how ever a simple google search returns this site: http://www.catacombae.org/jlrarx.html#rarlib

Also for .zip files, Java has an InflaterInputStream http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html

It also has specific subclasses for GZIP and ZIP files.

There are other compression methods as well: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

To specifically answer your question:  Yes there is good code to unzip a zip file.  The api is linked above http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html

If you have any problems when writing your code post a more specific question.